# Python 2.7: if-else statement with different indentation

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I'm doing an online course on Python 2.7 and one thing on if-else statements threw me off a bit:

```
def is_prime(num):
    for n in range(2,num):
        if num%n == 0:
            print "Not prime"
            break       
    else:
        print "Number is prime"
```

I know what the function does, but what is confusing me here is why Python understands and accepts the syntax of the if-else part (it wasn't explained in the video I was watching either). I would've expected the `else` to be at the same level of the `if` statement. Of course this would mean you'd get "Number is prime" a bunch of times for everything except 3, so it's great that this works as it is, but I'm looking for some sort of rule when I can do this. I tried googling it, but I haven't found this case on the normal tutorial sites.

Comment: That's not actually an if-else.

Comment: The else has nothung to do with the if. The else is for the 'for'

Comment: @lalala That makes sense, I simply didn't know that `for`could have an `else`. Thank you!

Comment: I was shocked as well when I found out previously.